# Manipulating email in Exchange Store from Tansport Agent

Tags: c#, exchange-server

I would like to append some text to an outbound email by writing a custom exchange transport agent.

Is there is a way in the agent to update the original message in the users sent-items folder on the Exchange store, and do this from the Hub server?

Comment: Adding text to outbound email is different than appending text to an email in the sent items folder. You mention both of these things. And why would you want to do the latter? The message has already been sent once it's in sent items.

Comment: On outbound messages, I would like to add an ID into the subject/body but then I want that ID to appear in the users sent item, so I would like it to go back to the users mailbox and update the original message.

Comment: You can certainly do an event sync or some other method to append to an email before it gets sent, but I'm not sure how you would edit the subject after the message was sent. In the Outlook gui if you double click a message to open it in a new window, you can then manually type into the subject field (most people don't know this) and when you close the window the new subject is saved. Not sure if you can do this programatically though.